# Programmatically modify Assembly Binding

Tags: microsoft.build

I have an issue working with [Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.aspx) which supposed to get fixed modifing my .exe.config file to add the following.

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
        <runtime>
           <assemblyBinding xmlns="urnchemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Engine" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

My problem is, I can't modify the file, I have to fix it by code, and I think that's supposed to be possible, right?

But how?, how can I modify my application so it runs as if the above changes were made on the config file?

Comment: thanks David... please tell what you did to fix the correct formatting of the xml

Comment: To format a block of code, you need a blank line before it, and then at least four spaces at the beginning of each line of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was just struggling with a similar problem. The key is to use the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event. Here's what my code looks like:

```
    public void LoadStuff(string assemblyFile)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += 
            new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);

        // Now load a bunch of types from the assembly...
    }

    Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var name = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        if (name.Name == "FooLibrary")
        {
            return typeof(FooClass).Assembly;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This completely ignores the version number and substitutes the already loaded library for any library reference named "FooLibrary". You can use the other attributes of the `AssemblyName` class if you want to be more restrictive. `FooClass` can be any class in the FooLibrary assembly.

Comment: This worked perfectly with MSTest running under TFS Build that does not pick up the config file.

Comment: I had some problems in debugger, where this event hit only for resource assemblies. In production works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to create a bootstrapping app which when launched would start your original app in a separate appdomain. When you set up the new domain you will be able to build the config file programmatically.

Comment: what do you mean by writing the config file? I don't want to programmatically modify it, I want to run my app as if my config was already modified.

Comment: not modify - build. The content of the config file is one of the parameters you can pass to AppDomain.CreateDomain method (inside the AppDomainSetup instance). This way you can build it on the fly